# loading a module from the local directory in Julia

Tags: julia

There are other questions related to this issue on SO but I think I tried the recommended solution without success though.

So, in the spirit of my baby-steps towards learning Julia, I tried to create a module locally. The folder structure of my module is as follows:

```
- TrimmedGrassmanAvwerage/
    - src/
        - TrimmedGrassmanAverage.jl
        - Utils/
            - dummy.jl
```

The contents of `dummy.jl` are simply:

```
function dummy(x)
    x + oneunit(x)
end
```

Similarly, the contents of `TrimmedGrassmanAverage` are:

```
module TrimmedGrassmanAverage

export Utils,
       dummy

include("Utils/dummy.jl")

end
```

Now, in my REPL I do the following:

```
julia> include("TrimmedGrassmanAverage/src/TrimmedGrassmanAverage.jl")
```

This returns:

```
Main.TrimmedGrassmanAverage
```

Now I do:

```
using TrimmedGrassmanAverage
```

This returns the error:

```
ERROR: ArgumentError: Package TrimmedGrassmanAverage not found in current   path:
- Run `Pkg.add("TrimmedGrassmanAverage")` to install the TrimmedGrassmanAverage package.
```

I thought that doing the `include("...") will put the package in the path and julia should be able to find it. However, clearly there is some more steps missing.

**EDIT**

However, I can do:

```
using Main.TrimmedGrassmanAverage
```

and then I can call:

```
TrimmedGrassmanAverage.dummy(10);
```

I am not sure why the `Main` namespace has to be added and also why I cannot just call `dummy` without the `Trimmed...` since I export the `dummy` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to load the module. Use either:

```
using Main.TrimmedGrassmanAverage
```

or

```
using .TrimmedGrassmanAverage
```

which will have the same effect. The reason is that when you run `include` your module gets defined within `Main` module scope. `using Something` does look for a package (and you have defined a module in a file only). Package lookup is governed by `LOAD_PATH` and `DEPOT_PATH` variables (see https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/Pkg/#Glossary-1).

EDIT: it actually seems that `dummy` is exported properly on Julia 1.0

```
julia> module TrimmedGrassmanAverage

export Utils,
       dummy

function dummy(x)
    x + oneunit(x)
end
end
Main.TrimmedGrassmanAverage

julia> using Main.TrimmedGrassmanAverage

julia> dummy(10)
11
```

at least on my Julia.

A side comment to your code is that `Utils` is not defined in the module and you try to export it (note that in Julia it does not matter from where you take the file that you `include` - this function works like copy-paste of code).

Comment: Thanks for replying! Ahhhh ok, this clarifies thing for me. very nice.

Comment: Actually I have checked that `dummy` is exported properly even if `Utils` is undefined (see my copy-paste in the answer). Can you double check that it does not work in your Julia. If yes please let me know.

Comment: I have added some comments about package lookup mechanics that might be also relevant for you in the future.