# How to include a file from a different directory in Julia 0.7?

Tags: import, julia

While learning Julia, I've stumbled on a basic task of including files from a different directory. I have two directories, *Core* and *Explore*, neither of which is the parent of the other; see the figure. Directory *Core* has a file *Core.jl* with

```
  module Core
    foo() = 1
  end
```

or it could be  a basic *.jl* file, not a module, with `foo()`.

[image: Directory structure]

The file *Explore.jl*, in directory *Explore*, needs to use `foo()` from *Core.jl*. So I tried putting the following lines into *Explore.jl*: `/Users/me/PycharmProjects/juliaProjects/src/Core/Core.jl`, `include("./Core.jl")` and other permutations. However I keep getting errors like

```
 ERROR: LoadError: could not open file    /Users/me/PycharmProjects/juliaProjects/src/Core/Core.jl
 Stacktrace:
[1] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
[2] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
[3] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
[4] include(::String) at ./client.jl:398
[5] top-level scope at none:0
[6] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
[7] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
[8] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
[9] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:239
[10] _start() at ./client.jl:432
in expression starting at /Users
```

***Question:*** What would be a correct `include` specification to put into a *jl.* file?

The environment is Julia 0.7 on Mac OS High Sierra. Note that I'm not using a shell, but an IDE, namely, the julia plug-in 0.3.3 for Intellij 2018.3.

I've checked other questions on SO, eg [loading a module from the local directory in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52519625/loading-a-module-from-the-local-directory-in-julia), [How to import custom module in julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200025/how-to-import-custom-module-in-julia/37220261#37220261), [What should path be to Julia source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37117020/what-should-path-be-to-julia-source-file), but they didn't seem to work.

***Edit:*** Based on the accepted answer, the file *Explore.jl* should include

```
cd("src/Core")
include("../Core/Core.jl")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot name a module `Core` because it is a reserved name and (have tested on my computer) creating such module crashes Julia in unexpected way.

Please see the example julia session below to understand how to create and load a module located in a different folder (please not that changing from `julia>` to `shell>` prompt is acquired by pressing `;` and exiting `shell>` is with *backspace*):

```
shell> mkdir mymod

shell> vim mymod/mod.jl

shell> more mymod/mod.jl
module MyMod
foo() = 1
end

shell> mkdir dir2

julia> cd("dir2")

julia> include("../mymod/mod.jl")
Main.MyMod

julia> using Main.MyMod

julia> MyMod.foo()
1
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't get any compilation errors from naming a module "Core". Suppose I already have two  separate folders, A and B, in a julia project in my IDE.  Neither is the parent of the other. The question is how a file in A can include a file from B. I'm not using a shell, so I'd like B.jl to have a hardcoded line `include A`. Thanks!

Comment: Last but not least perhaps what you really need is o create your own a package? https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0/stdlib/Pkg/